# What does $(document.body) mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$ is the name of a function. It is being passed the document's body DOM element. Typically $ is used to represent a JavaScript library. Most commonly **jQuery**. In jQuery it selects the body element.

Answer (score 9):

The `document.body` in javascript is a direct reference to the DOM element representing the `<body>` portion of the page.

The `$()` part depends on how it is used. `$` could be a variable name, and `()` after a variable or property name attempts to call a function stored in that variable or property.

So if you have:

```
var $ = function() { alert('howdy'); };
```

Then this:

```
$();
```

...will call that function, and trigger the alert.

Functions can accept arguments, so you could modify the function above to accept the `document.body` element as an argument, and `alert()` its `innerHTML` (for example);

```
  // alerts the innerHTML of the element it receives
var $ = function( elem ) { alert( elem.innerHTML ); }; 

$( document.body ); // Passes the element when calling the $ function
```

Answer (score 0):

it passes a DOMElement reference to the jQuery object/function so that a jQuery object is returned where `[0]` contains the reference and the context is of the body.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has meaning in jquery or prototype (or other frameworks), not in pure javascript. `$` is a function, in prototype it extends `document.body` with framework methods.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply passing an argument to a function named "$"

```
function $(someargument){
    ....
}
```

In this case the argument being passed is document.body

Typically Jquery uses $, so in that case probably someone wanted to use Jquery functions directly on the body i.e. wrapping the body in jquery.

```
$(document.body).html("hi");
```

(probably not a good idea to do that, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

check out the [SymbolHound results](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%24%28document.body%29) for "$(document.body)"